# How to show the index the user is currently with react-window List + Infinte Loader

Tags: reactjs, infinite, react-virtualized, react-window

I came to this problem when I wanted to show my user at which point he/she was on the list when they were scrolling. In short, I wanted to have a counter indicating the current index of the visible Row.

This can be achieved with `onItemsRendered`.

However, when using [react-window-infinite-loader](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window-infinite-loader) that prop is taken from the children's value needed to load else it is stuck to the loading state.

```
onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return the desired state, `onItemsRendered` needs to receive `visibleStartIndex` and `visibleStopIndex`. To get the current row and return the correct state, try the following:

```
<List
  className="List"
  height={200}
  itemCount={1000}
  itemSize={200}
  onItemsRendered={({ visibleStartIndex, visibleStopIndex }) => {
    this.setState({ counter: visibleStartIndex + 1 });
    return onItemsRendered({ visibleStartIndex, visibleStopIndex });
  }}
  ref={ref}
  width={300}
>
  {Row}
</List>
```

In addition here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-list-counter